# Node.js http request memory usage

Tags: node.js

I use nodejs wrote a simple code to crawler website all url.

When I run the code, the memory usage keep growing up, even I don't put any data to chunk and queue.

How should I do to prevent an increase in memory usage.

```
var http = require("http");

var options = {
    host: "...",
    path: "...",
    method: "GET",

    chunk: "",
    queue: []
}

function http_request(options) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
            if(res.statusCode === 200){
                res.on('data', function(chunk){
                    options.chunk += chunk;
                });
                res.on('end', function(){
                    http_request_chunk_handler(options);
                });
            }
            else {
                res.destroy();
                http_request_set(options)
            }
        });
        req.end();
    }, 1000);
}

function http_request_chunk_handler(options){
    //do somthing here, put some url into options.queue
    //write data to local file
    http_request_set(options);
}

function http_request_set(options){
    //do somthing here, shift queue item to option.path and reset option.chunk
    http_request(options);
}

http_request(options);
```

Comment: Keep dumping data to disk!

Comment: It looks like you just keep adding more and more data to `options.chunk`.

Comment: options.chunk will be reset to "" when call http_request_set